# How to parse the iBeacon on MacOS (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, parsing, ibeacon, beacon

I work with iBeacons in my project and I need to extract major, minor, UUID, txPower and beacon type values from advertisement data.

I get advertisement data from CBCentralManagerDelegate:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
```

Then I get major, minor, uuid and txPower values:

```
var uuidBytes: [UInt8] = [0]
var majorBytes: UInt16 = 0
var minorBytes: UInt16 = 0
var txPower: UInt16 = 0

let uuidRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(4, 16)
let majorRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(20, 2)
let minorRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(22, 2)
let powerRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(24, 1)

data.getBytes(&uuidBytes, range: uuidRange)
let proximityUUID: NSUUID = NSUUID(uuidBytes: &uuidBytes)

data.getBytes(&majorBytes, range: majorRange)
let majorBytesBig: uint16 = (majorBytes >> 8) | (majorBytes << 8)

data.getBytes(&minorBytes, range: minorRange)
let minorBytesBig: UInt16 = (minorBytes >> 8) | (minorBytes << 8);

data.getBytes(&txPower, range: powerRange)
```

But how I can get beacon type? (0x02 and 0x15 values in iBeacon specification)

**UPDATE**: I found next function in Obj-C for determining beacon type

```
- (BOOL)advDataIsBeacon:(NSData *)data
{
    Byte expectingBytes [4] = { 0x4c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x15 };
    NSData *expectingData = [NSData dataWithBytes:expectingBytes length:sizeof(expectingBytes)];

    if (data.length > expectingData.length)
    {
        if ([[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, expectingData.length)] isEqual:expectingData])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

but it not working in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will help to determine whether the advertisement data is a iBeacon.

```
private func isBeacon(_ data: NSData) -> Bool {
    var beaconType: UInt16 = 0
    let beaconTypeRange = NSMakeRange(2, 1)
    data.getBytes(&beaconType, range: beaconTypeRange)

    if (beaconType != 0x02) {
        return false
    }

    var beaconTypeLength: UInt16 = 0
    let beaconTypeLengthRange = NSMakeRange(3, 1)
    data.getBytes(&beaconTypeLength, range: beaconTypeLengthRange)

    if (beaconTypeLength != 0x15) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Also, see "Proximity Beacon Specification. Release R1"

Answer (score 0):

The 0215 can be found here:

```
let beaconTypeCode: NSRange = NSMakeRange(2, 2)
```